# Filtering Arrays Containing Multiple Data Types in Swift3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, filter

I have an array like:-

```
var arrayData : Array<Dictionary<String, [BottleModel]>> = []
```

Bottle model :-

```
class BottleModel: NSObject {

    var name : String
    var price : Int
    var reviews : Int
    var category : String
    var quantity : String
    var id : String
    var shopData : ShopModel
}
```

I want filtered array where price is > 2000

I tried `let searchByInts = arrayData.filter({m in m.price < 200})`
 but getting below error:

> Contextual closure
>   type '(Dictionary) -> Bool' expects 1 argument,
>   but 0 were used in closure body

How to filter such kind of array based on price

Comment: Price is String and you can not compare it with Sring

Comment: try this rrayData.filter({m in Int(m.price) < 200})

Comment: @MikeAlter, Good catch. I update my model

Comment: @MikeAlter, Error occurred:- Value of type 'Dictionary<String, [BottleModel]>' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Array<BottleModel>>') has no member 'price'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
let searchByInts = arrayData.filter { $0.values.contains { $0.contains { $0.price > 2000 } } }
```

By the way please write the following using literals:

```
var arrayData : [[String : [BottleModel]]] = []
```

Still no idea if that is what you actually want because your goal is *very* unclear. You have an array of dictionaries of arrays which actually contain the values you want to filter out. *If* a `BottleModel` costs more than 2000 do you want to keep the entire array it is contained in and the dictionary that array is in? You might want to map the entire data into one flat array before or after filtering.

Alternative using `flatMap`:

```
let flat = arrayData.flatMap { $0.values.flatMap { $0 } }
let searchByInts2 = flat.filter { $0.price < 200 } // or some other criteria
```

Comment: This works fine. What if I want to concatenate two conditions like:- price > 200 && reviews > 50

Comment: @pkc456 you can just do that and expand the most inner block: `$0.price > 200 && $0.reviews > 50`.